# Should I use +load to generate a singleton?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I'm writing a singleton class, and I usually do this:

```
@interface MySingleton
+ (instancetype) instance;
@end

@implementation MySingleton
+ (instancetype) instance {
    static MySingleton *instance;
    if (!instance) {
        instance = [MySingleton new];
    }
    return instance;
}
@end
```

But I recently considered this pattern:

```
@interface MySingleton
+ (instancetype) instance;
@end

@implementation MySingleton
static MySingleton *instance;
+ (void) load {
    instance = [MySingleton new];
}
+ (instancetype) instance {
    return instance;
}
@end
```

I find this more elegant and easier to understand, but this will be my first time using `+load`. **Are there any pitfalls that I might not expect? Is there any reason this would be a bad idea?**

Comment: Have you read https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-05-22-objective-c-class-loading-and-initialization.html?

Comment: @JoshCaswell no, but thank you! I didn't expect such Obj-C knowledge from a Python blog!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+load` has been deprecated/removed for Swift code. While existing ObjC code will still execute it (even if called from Swift), new code should not rely on it. The `dispatch_once` approach that @gnasher729 references is strongly preferred, and has the benefit of being lazy (while `+load` slows down launch; `dispatch_once` doesn't force construction until first usage). The `dispatch_once` Singleton is even a built-in code-snippet in Xcode. Apple provides the recommended implementation in [Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html).

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static id _sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedInstance;
}
```

(Or in Swift)

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
}
```

The naming `sharedInstance` (or better, `sharedFoo` for the class `Foo`) is preferred over `instance`. See `+[NSURLSesssion sharedSession]`, etc. This captures the real nature of singleton in ObjC, which is not *really* Singleton. There is just a single well-known instance. You are usually free to instantiate additional instances using `+new` or `+alloc`. `+instance` sounds like it does the same thing as `+new`, create a fresh instance. `+sharedInstance` makes it clear that this is an instance shared by other callers.

*As a side-note, I'd mention that many in the ObjC community have been [gradually moving away from singletons](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/singletons/) in recent years because of the difficulties they create in testing, their creation of global mutable state, and general inflexibility. Manual dependency injection (i.e. just setting properties or passing parameters, not complex DI frameworks) has been growing in favor. This is far from universal, and I'm not claiming Singleton is an anti-pattern in ObjC, but I do encourage you to avoid Singleton when it is not a huge benefit. For years it was my go-to solution to many problems, but times and patterns change.*

Comment: Thanks for all the cross-language info! Unfortunately, Swift is only a pipe dream for our app ATM (we must support iOS 7). What if I used `+initialize` instead of `+load`? Could I put `dispatch_once` in there?

Comment: There's no reason to do so. Just use the pattern that Apple recommends. The problem with both `+load` and `+initialize` is that they turn instance creation into "action at a distance." Putting it directly in `+sharedInstance` makes it clear exactly what's going on. `+initialize` also has subtle subclassing behavior. Not hard, but why introduce the complexity? The `dispatch_once` pattern is also what Cocoa devs expect. Why be surprising and force other devs to have to work through whether your code is ok? Just use the standard approach. It works great.

Comment: What @RobNapier said.  And if the "lazy" aspect of a dispatch_once() is unpalatable, you can always call `[MyClass sharedInstance]` from early in your app's lifecycle to guarantee the singleton is created.  In general, though, singleton creation shouldn't be too expensive (or the initialization should be moved off the calling thread).

Comment: @RobNapier your words haunted me over these few days. You mention that putting the singleton's initialization in `+initialize` is bad because it's "action at a distance". But, isn't this distant action a central part of the Cocoa design pattern? Like passing a selector to a notification center, or registering a delegate? It's harder to track down what's going on, but it runs more reliably.

Comment: Putting initialization logic into `+initialize` splits it from the point of use. There's a cost to that. You should get some benefit for it if you're going to pay that cost. Once upon a time, there was a benefit (easy thread-safety), but then we got `dispatch_once`, which gave us thread safety without splitting up the code. Notifications and delegation provide a stronger decoupling benefit, but even those are falling out of favor since we've been able to pass blocks (which again, tend to move related code together). Apple has steadily reduced its use of non-block APIs.

Comment: This is not to say that delegation and notification are antipatterns. They're perfectly fine patterns for certain uses. But we use them much less today then we did before blocks were added.

Answer (score 1):

There is a widely used pattern to create singletons using dispatch_once. There is absolutely no reason whatsoever why anyone would create a singleton in any different way. Instead you want to use some deeply obscure technology (which for example doesn't work once you switch to Swift).

By the way, try calling some class method to configure your singleton before it is created. Doesn't work with +load.

By the way, your "usual way" isn't thread safe.

Comment: Doesn't `dispatch_once` run through the same logic as my first snippet? I'm attracted to the `+load` solution due to its lack of conditionals. Could you elaborate on why "There is absolutely no reason whatsoever anyone would create a singleton in any different way"? That seems rather broad. Also, please elaborate on your second and third paragraphs. On a more personal note, your tone here is rather condescending, so you might want to work on this ;)

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero The difference between dispatch_once and your first snippet is that dispatch_once is thread safe and your solution is not.

Comment: @Avt can you elaborate on how my solution is not thread-safe?

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero There is no barrier to a second thread testing `if(!shared)` after another thread has already evaluated if(!shared) and decided to allocate an instance.   You need an execution barrier and `dispatch_once()` is both barrier and ensures a single pass.